# Grep the name from package.json file

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I want to grep name from package.json. My file looks like below. Name is in second line of the file.

```
 {
  "name": "Proje",
  "version": "1.0.0",
```

Output should be only `Proje`

Comment: Why grep specifically? there are much more robust ways of extracting elements from json e.g. `jq -r '.name' package.json`

Comment: This method is working. Thanks  a lot. But I need a shell script. Is there a accurate way to do it by using shell commands? I used this command and It shows the required output.`grep -ri "name" package.json |head -n 1 | cut -c 12-16`

Comment: JSON is sufficiently complex to require a proper parser, like XML, CSV, YAML, ...

Comment: Suppose your package.json looked like `{` (newline) `"version": "0.1.name",` (newline) `"name": "Proj", ...` , then the grep solution is broken because the first "name" appears in an unexpected place..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the input file is exactly the format shown; pure *POSIX* shell, no external utils:

```
while read a b ; do 
    [ "$a" = '"name":' ] && { b="${b%\"*}" ; echo "${b#\"}" ; break ; }
done < package.json
```

Output:

```
Proje
```

Comment: Thank you so much above command is working properly

Answer (score 2):

This line will extract the string value of name in `package.json`

`cat package.json | grep "name" | cut -d':' -f 2 | cut -d'"' -f 2`

example:

```
Hello-Kittys-MBP app-build % cat package.json | grep "name"
  "name": "@itential/app-build",

Hello-Kittys-MBP app-build % cat package.json | grep "name" | cut -d'"' -f 4
@itential/app-build
```

Comment: What if the name contains `:`?

Comment: here is another try one of my co-workers came up with:

grep -o '"name": "[^"]*' package.json | grep -o '[^"]*$'

Answer (score 1):

I used below commands to accessing package.json file and extract the name and also the version. All are working and thank you so much for your support.

```
grep -ri "name" package.json |head -n 1 | cut -c 12-16 

cat package.json | grep name | head -1 | awk -F: '{ print $2 }' | sed 's/[ ",]//g' 

node -p "require('./package.json').name" 

while read a b ; do
   [ "$a" = '"name":' ] && { b="${b%\"*}" ; echo "${b#\"}" ; break ; }
done < package.json

jq -r '.name' package.json
```

Comment: The code `cat package.json | grep name | head -1` can be simplified to just `grep -m1 name package.json`

Comment: @agc `grep -m1 name package.json | awk -F: '{ print $2 }' | sed 's/[ ",]//g'` yes It also working. Thank you so much